# Is there an adb command to move the mobile screen a few millimeters to the right?

Tags: android, command, adb, screen, resolution

sorry for my bad english. I speak Spanish and I am using the translator.

My problem is that I bought a Tecno brand cell phone and apparently I just noticed that the screen is a little further to the right than normal. I realized why the Google keyboard is not centered, it is not something that affects the performance of the phone but I would like to solve it.

I saw that there was a command with adb to change the resolution of the phone, I would like to know if there is one to move the virtual screen a few millimeters to the left.

I was looking for adb commands but I didn't find any guide that showed me all the available commands. I have searched Facebook groups looking for an answer that would turn on my light bulb but I have had no luck.

Comment: So you bought a manipulated device (hopefully just because of a repaired screen that not fully matches the old dimension). And you really trust such a device?